# Selenium 3.0 Chrome driver throwing exception for driver.switch

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Updated to Selenium 3.0 and running the test in chrome driver, this is my code:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

it's throwing below exception. Any input on this issue?

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field
>   com.google.gson.JsonNull.INSTANCE from class
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:95)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:143)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convertObject(BeanToJsonConverter.java:86)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.BeanToJsonConverter.convert(BeanToJsonConverter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:289)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:147)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:157)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.defaultContent(RemoteWebDriver.java:967)

Comment: As suggestion in one forum updated RestAssured to latest version, but Issue is not resolved. But If I change the driver.switchTo().defaultContent() to driver.switchTo().parentFrame(); then it works fine.